# Redshift 1+z - CMB Temperature lower?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, astrophysics, galaxies, cosmic-microwave-background

I know that $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} = 1 + z$

Suppose a galaxy had redshfit $z=3$. Does this mean that the wavelength becomes $4\lambda$?

Then by wien's law where $\lambda \propto \frac{1}{T}$, does this mean that the temperature now observed is $\frac{1}{4} \times 2.73 K$?

Comment: We  might *observe* the wavelength $\lambda$ as $4\lambda$, but does not mean that the *emitted* photon had a wavelength $4\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. The redshift $z$ is defined, as you already know, by $$z+1=\frac{\lambda_{\text{now}}}{\lambda_{\text{then}}}$$
If we consider a photon that was emitted at redshift $z=3$ the formula yields $$\frac{\lambda_{\text{now}}}{\lambda_{\text{then}}}=4$$ this tells us that the wavelength we observe now is four times as big as the wavelength when the photon was emitted. This does not say anything about the wavelength of the photon as it was emitted (except through $\lambda_{\text{now}}$, which we may be able to determine experimentally).

Comment: I was doing a basic astrophysics problem - to find the temperature of the observed CMB radiation, given that z = 3 The soution wrote $4 \times 2.73 K$ instead of $\frac{1}{4} \times 2.73 K $, which confused me.

Comment: 2.73 Kelvin is the temperature that is measured *now*. Does that help?

Comment: @user44840 z=3 has nothing to do with CMB, which was emitted at roughly z=1000.